# Metabase: Date Range filter to dashboards created by native query

Tags: druid, metabase

I use [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com) for data visualization.

[Druid](http://druid.io/) (imply-2.2.3) is data storage.

Created **Metabase Questions** I put on the dashboard and filter them all by **Date Range**.

When I try to add Date Range filter to question created by native query, metabase just can't find timestamp field for filtering and says: '**No valid fields**':
[image]

Same problem even if I convert question, created by UI constructor to native query by using  "**View native query**" option:

[image]

Generated Native query to Druid:

```
{
    "intervals": ["1900-01-01/2100-01-01"],
    "granularity": {
        "type": "period",
        "period": "P1D",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "context": {
        "timeout": 60000
    },
    "queryType": "timeseries",
    "dataSource": "DotmailerCampaign",
    "aggregations": [{
        "type": "javascript",
        "name": "sum",
        "fieldNames": ["numOpens"],
        "fnReset": "function() { return 0 ; }",
        "fnAggregate": "function(current, x) { return current + (parseFloat(x) || 0); }",
        "fnCombine": "function(x, y) { return x + y; }"
    }],
    "descending": false
}
```

What is missed?